# Select only last logs from mysql table, use DISTINCT of multiple column

Tags: mysql

I have table named `logs` that have primary column `ID`, and other columns are: `order_id, log_name, value, user_id` and `date`.

I'm trying to get rows where `order_id + log_name` will be unique value to have only last change of every cell in my orders table.

I've tried `DISTINCT`, but it works only with one column.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample data, expected output, and your attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well your problem, you can achieve this by making a subselect that transforms the table before applying the distinct or group by clause:

Suppose you have the log table

```
select distinct subtbl.Name from (select first_name + last_name as "Name" from log) as subtbl;
```

Or with group by:
    select subtbl.Name from (select first_name + last_name as "Name" from log) as subtbl group by subtbl.Name;

If you only want to get one row then you can add 'limit row, offset' at the end of the sentence

```
select subtbl.Name from (select first_name + last_name as "Name" from log) as subtbnl group by subtbl.Name limit 0, 1; -- this will take the first value
```

As i can see if you have an ID column i suppose that will be unique, if its numeric and auto increment column, you can get the last stored value with this:

```
select * from log order by id desc limit 0, 1;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Throws error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias :(

Comment: I missed to put the as aliasName in the sentences. I've edited the response, and now it should not return any error

Comment: Thank you, it works fine! But when I have two rows with same first_name+last_name I want to select that, which have bigger primary key ID, do you know how perform this?

Comment: As you are only getting the last value, if you order the subquery by PK desc (select first_name + last_name as "Name" from log order by primaryKeyField desc) and you have the limit 0, 1 you'll get only the most recent register.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with group by and limit.

*For example*

```
SELECT * FROM logs GROUP BY order_id, log_name ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: Error: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: It works if remove parenthesis: SELECT * FROM logs GROUP BY order_id, log_name